# Sort NSArray using sortedArrayUsingFunction

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, cocoa, nsarray

Any good example of sorting a NSArray using sortedArrayUsingFunction ?

TY!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSArray *sorted_bookings = [myUnsortedArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:Sort_Bookingdate_Comparer context:self];   

NSInteger Sort_Bookingdate_Comparer(id id1, id id2, void *context)
{
    // Sort Function
    Booking* booking1 = (Booking*)id1;  
    Booking* booking2 = (Booking*)id2;  


    return ([booking1.BOOKING_DATE compare:booking2.BOOKING_DATE]); 
}
```

This I used to sort bookings by bookingdate. Booking is a class with a synthesized instance variable called BOOKING_DATE.

Comment: I was wondering if it returned a sorted array or if it sorts the array (myUnsortedArray) itself. Iguess ur example answers that. TY!

Comment: In my case I wanted a new array. But if your array is a NSMutableArray  there is an instance method that just sorts the array. Just as in the example of Bogatyr

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 intValue];
    int v2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Close analogue using NSMutableArray:

```
[opponentMatchDicts sortUsingFunction:compareMatchByDate context:nil];
...


static int compareMatchByDate( id m1, id m2, void *context)
{
    NSDictionary *mDict1 = (NSDictionary *) m1;
    NSDictionary *mDict2 = (NSDictionary *) m2;
    NSDate *date1 = [mDict1 objectForKey:kMatchNSDate];
    NSDate *date2 = [mDict2 objectForKey:kMatchNSDate];

    int rv = [date1 compare:date2];
    return rv;
}
```