# Sort a NSMutableArray of NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsinteger

What is the best and fastest way to sort an `NSMutableArray` of `NSInteger`?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `NSMutableArray` of `NSInteger`. What is your real question?

Comment: I guess he means instances of `NSNumber` representing `NSInteger` values.

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147218/sort-nsarray-using-sortedarrayusingfunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you [sort any array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12) or [sort any mutable array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW6).