# iOS sortedArrayUsingFunction function signature confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read [Sort NSArray using sortedArrayUsingFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147218/sort-nsarray-using-sortedarrayusingfunction) and it's possible that the following question is about to reveal my deep ignorance of Objective-C.

The answers to the questions above suggest that I need a method whose signature is of the form 
`- (NSInteger) sortFunction(id id1, id id2, void *context);`.

But all the code I have has function signatures of the form

```
- (NSInteger) sortFunction:(id) id1, foo:(id) id2, bar:(void *) context;
```

When I change my sortFunction's declaration to be of the first form, I get all kinds of errors:  A "expected ';' before '(' token" in both myclass.h and myclass.m, and in a few other files; the same "'sortFunction' not declared" message that I get the other way; and "expected '{' before '(' token" on the declaration of sortFunction in myclass.m.

When I use it in the second form, I get an error on my call of `sortedArrayUsingFunction` -- namely "function "sortFunction" not declared".

What am I missing?

Comment: you say "all kinds of errors" - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method requires an actual function, not a method. If you want to use a method, you would use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` and it's expected that this method will be defined on the objects themselves. So, if you have an array of `NSString`s, for example, you'd call some compare selector on `NSString`. To use the function, you'd do something like this:

```
// this orders by the object's memory location -- not really very useful in the real world
NSInteger my_compare_function(id obj1, id obj2, void* context) {
  if( obj1 < obj2 ) return NSOrderedAscending;
  else if( obj1 > obj2 ) return NSOrderedDescending;
  else return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

This function needs to be somewhere in scope of where you call it, and then you'd call it like this:

```
NSArray* sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:my_compare_function context:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

This code example takes a function.  If you don't want a function, you can also use a block using this overload:

```
[unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)cmptr
```

Here's the function code:

```
NSInteger sortNames(id id1, id id2, void *context)
{
    // Sort Function
    NSString* name1 = (NSString*)id1;  
    NSString* name2 = (NSString*)id2;  

    return ([name1 compare:name2]); 
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSArray *unsorted = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Bob", @"Avril", nil];
    NSArray *names = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingFunction:sortNames context:nil];   

    for (NSString* item in names)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2011-10-17 20:59:01.790 Craplet[1474:707] Avril
2011-10-17 20:59:01.792 Craplet[1474:707] Bob
2011-10-17 20:59:01.792 Craplet[1474:707] John
```

Comment: I always keep a Craplet cmd line project open @ home & work to try out code :)

Answer (score 0):

The first format is correct, please post the errors you're getting to elaborate. Meanwhile here's an example.

```
NSInteger personSort(id p1, id p2, void *context)
{
    NSString *name1 = [(MYPersonClass *)p1 firstName];
    NSString *name2 = [(MYPersonClass *)p2 firstName];
    return [name1 compare:name2]
}

NSArray *sortedPerson = [allPeople sortedArrayUsingFunction:personSort context:NULL];
```